# how to convert string to json having comma in value

Tags: java, json, string

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;

 String strJSON = "{items=[{id=1647, address=sample, person=null, date=1686616249817, read=0, status=-1, type=1, subject=null, body=registration done successful, click on this to know more, serviceCenter=+910000000000}], total=1570}".replaceAll("=",":");
 System.out.println(JsonPath.parse(strJSON).jsonString());
```

In above sample key "body " value have comma

Instead of this output:

```
{"items":[{"id":1647,"address":"sample","person":null,"date":1686616249817,"read":0,"status":-1,"type":1,"subject":null,"body":"registration done successful","click on this to know more, serviceCenter":"+910000000000"}],"total":1570}
```

I want output to be

```
{"items":[{"id":1647,"address":"sample","person":null,"date":1686616249817,"read":0,"status":-1,"type":1,"subject":null,"body":"registration done successful,click on this to know more", "serviceCenter":"+910000000000"}],"total":1570}
```

Comment: Do you want `body=registration, done, successful` using Java?

Comment: The string doesn't contain a valid JSON document. The syntax is wrong.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour, Instead of this output: {"items":[{"id":1647,"address":"sample","person":null,"date":1686616249817,"read":0,"status":-1,"type":1,"subject":null,"body":"registration done successful","click on this to know more, serviceCenter":"+910000000000"}],
I want  {"items":[{"id":1647,"address":"sample","person":null,"date":1686616249817,"read":0,"status":-1,"type":1,"subject":null,"body":"registration done successful,click on this to know more", "serviceCenter":"+910000000000"}],"total":1570}

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
String strJSON = "{items=[
{id=1647, 
address=sample, 
person=null, 
date=1686616249817, 
read=0, 
status=-1, 
type=1, 
subject=null, 
body=\"registration done successful, click on this to know more\", 
serviceCenter=+910000000000}], 
total=1570}"
.replaceAll("=",":");



System.out.println(JsonPath.parse(strJSON).jsonString())
```

You need to escape the double quotes.
Personal Tip: Check Out the json Syntax, this Takes ~60 minutes. :)
Here is a nice short article:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm

In general, you must put Strings between doublequotes in Json. The comma is used to split the member fields, like parameters in Java methods.
And because you are in a String already, you need to escape the doublequotes.